# Change (only) the color of RatingBar

Tags: android, android-studio, ratingbar

I'm trying to change the stars color to yellow.
I don't want to use another style(!), just changing the color of the built-in stars in the RatingBar.

I've read a few tutorials how to change the style, they are all pretty similar.   But for some reason it just doesn't work for me.
Anyway, since I just want to change the color, and not the whole style, I used the code below:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_details);
        rbBookRating = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.rbRating);
        rbBookRating.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating, boolean fromUser) {

            }
        });
        LayerDrawable stars = (LayerDrawable) rbBookRating.getProgressDrawable();
        stars.getDrawable(2).setColorFilter(Color.YELLOW, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
        stars.getDrawable(1).setColorFilter(Color.CYAN, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
        stars.getDrawable(0).setColorFilter(Color.RED, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
    }
```

layout

```
<RatingBar
android:id="@+id/rbRating"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:isIndicator="true"
android:stepSize="0.5" />
```

(It seems that) My app crashes right after this line:

```
LayerDrawable stars = (LayerDrawable) rbBookRating.getProgressDrawable();
```

Any suggestion why?

Comment: Can you add the logcat error that you are seeing?

Comment: please add logcat @Nick

Answer (score 2):

I just needed to use:

```
DrawableCompat.setTint(rbBookRating.getProgressDrawable(), Color.YELLOW);
```

Thanks anyway...

Answer (score 1):

**Firstly create a theme**

```
 <style name="RatingBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/duskYellow</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/lightGrey</item>
  </style>
```

**Then add this in your xml**

```
<RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/rating"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:numStars="5"
        android:stepSize="1"
        android:theme="@style/RatingBar"/>
```